# cdn for static resources

Tags: performance

I'm analysing a performance problem and currently looking for more information around the usage of CDN for static resources that are part of our App. In previous releases, Salesforce released two features:

[Enable CDN to Load Lightning Experience Faster](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lc_cdn.htm): (winter '19) enabling this feature loads the static resources for the Lightning Component framework from Akamai's CDN

[Get Faster Page Loads in Your Community](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_cdnupdate.htm): (spring '19) enabling this feature loads (per [the help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_cdn.htm&type=5)) the following resources from Akamai's CDN:

- Resources that are accessible in a public community without authentication, including HTML, JavaScript, CSS, image, and font files
- Resources that are configured as publicly cacheable, such as Salesforce static resources with the Cache Control setting configured to Public

The second features looks very promising, but we do not have communities configured in most of our Orgs. Is there a similar feature that was introduced previously or that is on the roadmap that can be used for Orgs without communities?

Answer (score 2):

I've raised a support Case at Salesforce for this too, and got a clear answer today: "Our Product team has responded saying that , lightning CDN only caches static resources that are served by salesforce. We do not have the ability to cache any non-salesforce static resources."

Next to that, the security review requirements include: "Required: all script and style resources must be loaded through static resources"; as our App is listed in the AppExchange, we cannot construct URLs to CDNs manually either.